# when i type first in textarea text not input in this after click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
    <script>
function ShortUrl(urlshort){

var url = urlshort;
var msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;
var alltext = msg;
if(msg){
alltext += ', '+ url;
}else{
alltext = url;
}
alert(alltext);
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = alltext;



}
</script>
<textarea name="msg" id="msg" cols="40" rows="5" class="txtareabox" ></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="short_url" value="abc.com" id="short_url"/>
<input type="button" value="insert" id="btnTxt" onclick="ShortUrl(short_url.value)" />
```

when i click on insert text sent to text area but when first write in textarea after this function work but textarea dont get value with short url

Comment: Your requirement is confusing. Please explain more.

Comment: i have a text area field and i will want to insert value of short_url on click on button in textarea field

Comment: @VishwaFauzdar your English is not very good. In the future you should add an example on jsfiddle.net so we can see more easily what it is you want and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Some minor changes, and check the fiddle to see it working.

```
//this needed to be .value not .innerHtml
document.getElementById("msg").value = alltext;

//this worked for me, and is better for seperation of concerns, it will help to keep your code cleaner.
document.getElementById("btnTxt").onclick = function(){ ShortUrl(short_url.value); };
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56yag47h/)

Comment: thanks lot, after making changeing in document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = alltext; to document.getElementById("msg").value = alltext; this work properly but after insert in textarea character counter not minus character because character counter work on onkeyup='limiter()' how set this on insert #james G

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the value (after appending short url) is not getting updated in textbox.

In your script replace last line with this:

```
document.getElementById("msg").value = alltext;
```

i.e. use value instead of innerHtml.

Working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tq8qb6LL/

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood, you may want something like this

```
     <script>
function ShortUrl(){

var url = document.getElementById("short_url").value;
var msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;
var alltext = msg;
if(alltext!=""){
alltext =alltext + ', '+ url;
}else{
alltext = url;
}
alert(alltext);
document.getElementById("msg").value = alltext;



}
</script>
<textarea name="msg" id="msg" cols="40" rows="5" class="txtareabox" ></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="short_url" value="abc.com" id="short_url"/>
<input type="button" value="insert" id="btnTxt" onclick="ShortUrl()" />
```